# How can I perform a value dependent pivot table/Groupby in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
      Tran ID    Category    Quantity 
   0   001          A           5
   1   001          B           2 
   2   001          C           3
   3   002          A           4
   4   002          C           2
   5   003          D           6
```

I want to transform it into:

```
      Tran ID       A      B      C      D       Quantity 
   0   001        True    True   True   False       10
   1   002        True    False  True   False        6
   2   003        False   False  False  True         6
```

I know I can use `groupby` to get the sum of quantity, but I can't figure out how to perform the pivot that I described.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) for indicators with `max` and add new column with aggregating `sum`:

```
#pandas 0.23+
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Tran ID')['Category'], dtype=bool).max(level=0)
#oldier pandas versions
#df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('Tran ID')['Category']).astype(bool).max(level=0)
s = df.groupby('Tran ID')['Quantity'].sum()

df2 = df1.assign(Quantity = s).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Tran ID      A      B      C      D  Quantity
0     001   True   True   True  False        10
1     002   True  False   True  False         6
2     003  False  False  False   True         6
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
print(df.drop('Category',1).join(df['Category'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool)).groupby('Tran ID',as_index=False).sum())
```

Or little easier to read:

```
df1 = df.drop('Category',1).join(df['Category'].str.get_dummies().astype(bool))
print(df1.groupby('Tran ID',as_index=False).sum())
```

Both output:

```
   Tran ID  Quantity      A      B      C      D
0        1        10   True   True   True  False
1        2         6   True  False   True  False
2        3         6  False  False  False   True
```

[`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`pandas.Series.str.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) is the way to do it.

Comment: I think you're missing a parenthesis at the end

Comment: Solution working with sample data, but if change second row to `1;001;A;2` it working uncorrect.Reason is aggregating `sum`

Comment: @jezrael I am gonna try.

Comment: @U9-Forward - What is your pandas version? In my pandas 0.24.2 it create 2 and 1 values instead `True` and `False`

Comment: @jezrael Sorry, but i am much lower, 0.19.2

Comment: @U9-Forward - Really old, upgrade it... :)

Comment: @jezrael Lol :-)

Comment: `Date: Dec 24, 2016 Version: 0.19.2` - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/